# optimizing code that contains a several foor lops and if-else statements in Python

Tags: python, optimization, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I red that

`lis2= map(str.strip, lis1)`

is faster and better-written than

```
lis2= []

for z in lis1:
    lis2.append(z.strip())
```

now, I have the following code:

```
    for item in sel:
        name = item.text  
        songs = []
        for song in item.find_next_siblings('div', class_="listalbum-item"):
            if song.find_previous_sibling('div', class_='album') == item:
                if 'www.somesite.com/lyrics' in song.find('a')['href']:
                    songs.append([song.text,  song.find('a')['href']])
                else:
                    songs.append([song.text, 'https://www.somesite.com/' + song.find('a')['href'][3:]])
        album[name] = songs
```

how can apply the concept above to that piece of code? To be honest the first question should be **is it necessary? really is it possible to optimize that?** , but anyway, some advices?

thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't really faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the real difference between the two fragments:

```
lis2= map(str.strip, lis1)
```

And:

```
lis2= []

for z in lis1:
    lis2.append(z.strip())
```

It's fair to say that, to many programmers, the first is more clearly written. After all, it literally says what is being done, not how it's done. Whenever you can do that, it's the better choice, as long as you're not sacrificing anything that's important (like, possibly, speed).

Another way of improving the readability would be to use better names and follow PEP8 coding conventions:

```
list2 = map(str.strip, list1)
```

But if it's 'better' or 'faster', really depends. The real difference is that the `map` example leaves it up to the implementation of `map` to decide how a list is constructed. On the inside of map, you could find code that just uses a `for` loop and `list.append()` as well, but it could also be some really complicated, but very efficient code that does it faster or using fewer resources somehow.

The reason people say using something like `map` is better (and why it's often faster) is that you're leaving the work up to a library function that has been specifically written to keep the implementation details away from you and others that read your code, and to allow you to benefit from improvements to that function over time.

It's quite possible though that, for your specific case, with your specific data, you know how to write something that performs even better. So, if speed is the objective, you may be able to improve on `map` for your case.

What the 'best' code is for you, depends on how you rank your code. Does readability (for others and your future self) get trumped by speed?

If your case, since you call some external library to search through an HTML document, it's very likely that will cost orders of magnitude more time than a simple for loop in Python, that's actually pretty clear as well.

Have you looked at ways of doing that work more optimally? For example, this bit:

```
    for song in item.find_next_siblings('div', class_="listalbum-item"):
        if song.find_previous_sibling('div', class_='album') == item:
```

`find_next_siblings` finds all document element siblings of the `item` that are a `listalbum-item` (apparently, a `song`) and for each of those, you check if the first sibling immediately before it that is an `album` is the `item`.

In other words, it appears that you're trying to loop over all the songs of the album, but do you expect songs in `sel` that are not on the album? If not, you should be able to optimise this code quite a bit - but it's hard to help improve the code without knowing what the content looks like.

Comment: Note that one of the things a `map` implementation can often do is to preallocate the required size of the output list (as it may know the size of the input list).  A `loop-append` cannot do this, and most dynamically reallocate from time to time.

Comment: @donkopotamus - yeah that's a good example of how the implementation of `map()` may be able to improve over a simple `for`+`.append()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This **can** be done as a list comprehension, and will be **faster** as a list comprehension ... but is certainly **not necessarily clearer** as a list comprehension:

```
[[song.text, 
  (song.find('a')['href'] 
   if 'www.somesite.com/lyrics' in song.find('a')['href'] 
   else 'https://www.somesite.com/' + song.find('a')['href'][3:])]
 for song in item.find_next_siblings('div', class_="listalbum-item")]
```

Comment: List comprehensions give marginal speedups that become increasingly marginal as the work in the body of the loop increases... They aren't meant for performance